# Malformed OpenID request

Tags: bug, openid

I'm trying to login to my account using my own OpenID provider server, which runs [simpleid](http://simpleid.koinic.net/). I get redirected to my server and confirm the login, but after being redirected back to Stack Overflow it fails to login. After debugging  my server a bit, it turned out that Stack Overflow sends a weird HTTP request in the [check_authentication](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#verifying_signatures) direct request: All fields are prefixed with `openid_` instead of `openid.`, like this (incomplete list of HTTP headers):

```
[openid_mode] => check_authentication
[openid_ns] => http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
```

I find nothing in the [OpenID 2.0 specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html) that allows for that, rather the opposite (section 4.1.2.):

> All of the keys in the request message MUST be prefixed with "openid.".

Comment: technically it is prefixed with openid...

Comment: @Tschallacka Note the full stop inside the quotes.

Comment: ah, missed that one. easy to miss